# Create simple OCMock unit test in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, unit-testing, ocmock

I configured OCMock to my static class library and I created simple method like this.

```
#import "IOSExample.h"
@implementation IOSExample

-(NSString *)MyTest
{
return @"Nuwanga";
}

-(int *)MyAge
{
    int a=5;
    int b=5;
    int product=a*b;
    return product;
}
 @end
```

In OCUnit test I created this method like bellow.

```
-(void)testMyAge
{
    int a=5;
    int b=5;
    int product=a*b;
    STAssertTrue((product > 0), @"The Product was less than zero");
}
```

My problem is How can I create return type test method in OCMock unit test ???

Thankz

Comment: Read the Documentation tab for [OCMock](http://ocmock.org).

Comment: I don't understand your question. OCMock is used to "mock" other objects, replace methods in order to write unit tests without external dependencies. Do you want to mock something or just write a normal unit test?

Comment: Also, that code is to simple to mock. There is no class to mock, just a method.

Comment: This class in NSObject class. I need to do unit test by using Mock object to the class. How I use this method correctlly :: id mock1=[OCMockObject mockForClass:]

Comment: What you want to mock here ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to do something like

```
-(void)testMyAge
{
    IOSExample *exampleUndertest = [[IOSExample alloc] init];


    STAssertTrue(([exampleUndertest MyAge] > 0), @"The Product was less than zero");
}
```

Regards,
Quentin

Answer (score 0):

For TDD you can modify your code as below

```
-(int *)MyAge:(int)inA and:(int)inB
{
    int product=inA*inB;
    return product;
}
```

And your test case will become like this

```
-(void)testMyAge
{
    int product=[sut MyAge:5 and:5];
    STAssertTrue((product > 0), @"The Product was less than zero");
}
```

I dont see any need for mocking in this case.